# Loading javascript file from rails 4 asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to get a jquery plugin (geocomplete) to work and am having an issue with my rails asset pipeline.

To get the plugin to work, I need to load a .js file called *jquery.geocomplete.js* located in my */vendor/assets/javascripts/* directory

In my application.js file I include *jquery.geocomplete*

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery.geocomplete
//= require jquery.geocomplete.min
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require_tree .
```

When I load my app in development mode, I can see in the source code that the following asset has been loaded:

```
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.geocomplete.js?body=1"></script>
```

However, the plugin requiring does not work. To get it to work I have to paste:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>
```

into my relevant view. (This then causes issues when I run in production mode in Heroku)

Can anyone tell me why the *myjquery.geocomplete.js* file will not run my plugin when I load it through the asset pipeline?

Any thoughts/ideas appreciated.